# What on-hit effects work on Fiora's ult?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does crit, Wit's End, Malady, or Madred's Bloodrazor proc with Fiora's ult?

Answer (score 2):

All on hit effects should proc with the following notes:

- Blade Waltz procs on-hit effects.
- Blade Waltz will not proc spell vamp or  Rylai's slow similarly with all spells and abilities that proc on-hit effects.
- Any on-hit effects that Blade Waltz procs will have their full effect and will not be reduced by hitting the same target.
- Tiamat will splash 50% of the damage dealt on each strike.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Fiora_the_Grand_Duelist/Ability_Details)

Comment: So, in essence, you could push out probably 1.5-2k damage to a single person with no problem. Thats a bit OP if you ask me, but then again there are ways to counter it, like going out of her LoS for example, or hourglass it.

Answer (score 0):

Tiamats work on Fiora's ult, but I'm not too sure about the Wit's End.

Answer (score 0):

Crits do not work but every on hit works including wits end

Answer (score 0):

I think that Black Cleaver and Wit's end will stack. Fiora's ultimate is like Warwick's ult, it does multiple hits on a target and should work with on-hit items.